# Is the Nikon 35mm f/1.8 AF-S being replaced?

Tags: lens, nikon, dslr

I need a fast lens with autofocus for taking indoor shots with my Nikon D3000. I have been looking at the Nikon 35mm f/1.8 AF-S for a while and now that I am ready to get one they are next to impossible to find. Is this lens being replaced or discontinued? If so does anyone have a recommendation for similar lens in the same price range?

Comment: Note that any AF-S lens will work on any camera without a built in focus motor. AF-S lenses have the focus motor built in. Just FYI.

Comment: It is an amazing lens, no wonder it is out of stock. I would backorder it and wait, it is a very good lens for the money. Not sure, if anything else provides the versatility and quality of this one for the money and auto focus on D3000.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a relatively new lens and popular lens, so it would shock me if it was being discontinued or replaced.

During the Christmas season, they became incredibly popular as presents and the supply dwindled (increasing the price considerably for a bit, even on Amazon).
It's one of the cheapest lenses available for DX cameras and not too shabby either!  The stores are probably still behind on the stocking from the holiday season.

Either give it time, or check out the Sigma 30mm f/1.4 or Nikon/Sigma 50mm f/1.4 - although these are more expensive. (Realize the Nikon 50mm f/1.8 won't autofocus on your D3000).

Comment: i just picked one up from my local camera shop last weekend, there were 2 avail, the guy said they are popular. call around your local shops, maybe reserve one from them.

Comment: I believe that both Nikon and Canon had to temporarily shut down their factories in Japan due to the earthquake and tsunami. I don't know any further details, but I'm sure it has impacted their production of products.

Answer (score 3):

It's only a couple of years old, and it fits a very good niche (DX, small, cheap, fast, relatively wide). I really doubt it will get discontinued soon.

But I doubt anyone except Nikon has anything more than speculation on this topic.

Similar lenses: You pretty much have to go with the 50mm to get anything with the same price point, speed, and quality. I'd recommend the 35mm f/2 AF-D (it's a very similar lens for not much more) except that it won't autofocus on your D3000.

Answer (score 1):

This lens was [launched just two years ago](http://www.nikon.com/about/news/2009/0209_nikkor_01.htm) — it's unlikely that it'd be discontinued or replaced so soon. In fact, they've been selling like hotcakes ever since that launch, and it seems like they're always on the verge of being out of stock. I suspect you're just seeing that at work. I'd go ahead and preorder from one of the big reputable places; it shouldn't be too long of a wait.

Answer (score 1):

These lenses are built in batches. It's probable that we're simply between container-loads from China - the last lot are getting rarer or have completely sold out in some markets, and the next haven't arrived yet.

Answer (score 1):

I got one a couple months ago, it's an amazing lens for the price. Like someone else said, preorder one and you'll be safe. If we consider the needs you mentioned, I'm afraid this is maybe the only match for a nikon DX for some simple reasons. It's also the best match, so cheer up! First, let's see the problem with alternatives:

- other good, fast and affordable nikon lenses around that focal
  lenght won't autofocus on DX cameras (no internal motor)
- the sigma 30 f1.4, its main competitor, is freaking sturdy and sports a beautiful BIG front diameter, for me it was love at first sight! it has a
  distance scale, but I would say it's optically
  inferior (distortion, glare). The autofocus might be not as accurate
  as with the nikkor (one could
  expect that), it weights much more(well, that's about taste, but on super light DXs it can get you kinda unbalanced), no manual/auto focus switch(this is true only in the version for nikons, I wonder why), **almost double the price**, a bit too wide for, say, portrait, architectural detail, still life (not that the nikkor is made for such things, but it's  a bit better - well, it's made for almost everything). The guy at the photo store even told me it's not as fast as they claim.

That said, I used the nikkor 35 for a while and I'm really satisfied. At 800 ISO f1.8 I get decent handheld shots at night outdoor with street lamps neon signs etc, and perfect shots indoor in average artificial light or outdoor at dawn/sunset. The bokeh is much better than I expected from photos I'd seen around, really good!

- IMHO its main flaw is purple fringing, rarely visible at first glance, still it's easy to get.

In the end, if I got back I wouldn't hesitate and I'd get it again. I'm sure with a bit of patience you'll get one, it's unlikely to be discontinued any soon.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how rare they are - I just hopped over to Amazon and [they have them in stock](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001S2PPT0) (as of this time).

It's a bit more money, but the Sigma 30mm f/1.4 [gets decent reviews](http://www.fredmiranda.com/reviews/showproduct.php?product=320&sort=7&cat=38&page=1) and gives you an wider aperture.

Comment: Your link doesn't work. But I'm seeing that Amazon themselves are actually out of stock, and are returning availability from a few third-party merchants.

Comment: Fixed the link - and yes it's through a third party but I'd say if you can find one on Amazon, it's not that rare.

Comment: But if it's out of stock at B&H, Adorama, and Amazon ("proper"), I think it's a pretty good sign that overall supply is pretty low. The third party prices that are available all have about a 20% price premium.

Comment: Oh, hey, please remove your Amazon referrer tag. Not okay, as you brought up youself on meta! http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/661/

Comment: Gah, whoops.  I'm so used to just grabbing the shortened URL that I forgot about the no-affiliate rule here.  Thanks for pointing that out Matt.

Comment: The difference between f/1.8 and f/1.4 isn't a stop, it's 2/3 stop.

Comment: Almost three quarters of a stop. :)

Comment: I just bought one from Best Buy last week (only retailer I could find that had them in stock and wasn't selling them with a ~20% premium), but it looks like there backordered there now too. :(

Answer (score 0):

I just ordered one from Jessops in the UK. It was on backorder so I rang them and they said they were doing an of 1000 lenses, and I would get mine on Friday. So, I don't think it's been discontinued, but there may have been recent supply chain changes.

Answer (score 0):

According to info passed by [Thom Hogan's site](http://bythom.com), Nikon's lens factory in Tochigi was affected by earthquake and therefore closed for almost two weeks. Therefore there could be shortage of many Nikon lenses. Also, the factory in Sendai making FX bodies was severely damaged.

Comment: The Nikon AF-S 35mm f/1.8 G DX isn't made in the Tochigi plant, it's made in China.
This lens was on backorder well before the earthquake in Japan, it's not being discontinued.